# Mapply recycling in R

Tags: r, mapply

I have written a function which undertakes arima modelling, outputs a table of coefficients and p-values, ranks the p-values and returns an arima model with no significant variables.

The function takes two inputs, a time series objects, and a data frame.

Here is the code:

```
  backward_stepwise<-function(x, y){
    repeat{
       arima_result<-auto_arima(x)
       arima_pvals<-p_calc(arima_result)
       arima_outputs<-run_outputs(arima_result, arima_pvals)
       arima_ranked<-rank_pval(arima_outputs)
       # temporary fix to .xreg being added to term names
       for(i in 1:length(arima_ranked$term)){
       arima_ranked$term<-gsub(arima_ranked$term, pattern = 'xreg.', 
       replacement = "")
     }
       remove_num_one<-remove_one(arima_ranked)
        # removed the cond_select function so that y and x write over 
        themselves
        y<-subset(y, select = colnames(y) != remove_num_one) 
        x<-as.ts(y)

    if(min(arima_ranked$rank, na.rm = TRUE) != 1){
    break

    }
  }

  return(arima_result)
 }
```

I am going to apply this to a list of time series objects and list of data frames

Example of time series list

```
CAN_V98
ADE_U91
ADE_V95
```

Example of data frames

```
CAN_V98
ADE_U91
ADE_V95
```

When I apply it view mapply or for loop, are either methods taking the values from the same index. I.e will the backward step-wise function strip variables from CAN_V98 and keep using CAN_V98 from the data frame list, or after performing its first loop it will use the second data frame from the list of data frames.

```
# Application via for loop
for(i in mkt_grd){
x<-list_ts_actual[[i]]
y<-list_df_actual[[i]]
ts_outputs[[i]]<-backward_stepwise(x, y) 
}

# Application via mapply
ts_outputs1<-mcmapply(backward_stepwise, list_ts_actual, 
list_df_actual,SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Thank you for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

`mapply` doesn't work like an embedded for loop ie. it will not run through every `j` for each `i` so to speak.

```
mapply(function(x, y){cat("x = ", x, " y = ", y, "\n")},
       x = 1:5, y = 1:5)

x =  1  y =  1 
x =  2  y =  2 
x =  3  y =  3 
x =  4  y =  4 
x =  5  y =  5
```

as you can see if it iterates through in parallel, if the length of list y is shorter it will recycle, ie,

```
mapply(function(x, y){cat("x = ", x, " y = ", y, "\n")},
       x = 1:5, y = 1:3)

x =  1  y =  1 
x =  2  y =  2 
x =  3  y =  3 
x =  4  y =  1 
x =  5  y =  2
```

Comment: My lists are the same length, I just wanted to make sure that variables aren't being stripped from the next data frame in the list

Comment: I think at the bottom of the question, you use a for loop and mapply to do the same thing, comparing the result should give the answer to your question?

Comment: @ Croote, I can check that no doubt, moreso just wanted to see the I was understanding the application of mapply was correct . Thankyou for the response